# else se imprime más de una vez

Tags: c

cuando ingreso un caracter, me manda el mensaje error de la sgte forma. si ingreso 4 letras, ddfs, me envia error 4 veces. o si ingreso 2 letras por ej, me envia --> error error. mi intención es que se salga del ciclo sólo si ingresa un número(ya que al ingresar un número xd deja de ser <1 y debería finalizar. mi else falla y no encuentro el error

```
 int xd=0;
while(xd<1){
    int a = getchar();
    if( isdigit(a) ){
    puts("OK");
        xd=xd+2;
    }

    else
    printf("Error");
}
```

Comment: necesito que le siga pidiendo ingresar hasta que ingrese un número, y con ese detengo el ciclo

Comment: entonces coloca el `break` dentro del `if`

Comment: lo que tu necesitas es un while no un if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que a la hora de mostrar el mensaje de error no actualizas `xd`, y como estás leyendo caracter a caracter... te saldrá el mensaje de error una vez por caracter no numérico que hayas introducido!!!

Para evitar el problema puedes limpiar el buffer de entrada (y no, no es recomendable usar `fflush`)

```
int xd=0;
while(xd<1){

  int a = getchar();
  if( isdigit(a) ){
    puts("OK");
    xd=xd+2;
  }
  else
  {
    for( a = getchar(); a != EOF && a != '\n'; a = getchar() );

    printf("Error");
  }
}
```

Ese bucle tan raro que ves ahí descartará todos los caracteres que haya en el buffer de entrada hasta que se tope con un salto de línea o con se vacíe el buffer. De esta forma el mensaje de error únicamente te saldrá una vez.

Answer (score 1):

Como dice @eyllanesc, la palabra clave `break` romperá el ciclo.

Recuerda que debes colocar `break` al fnal de todo el bloque de código dentro del `if` porque el código se ejecuta desde arriba hacia abajo y salir del ciclo será lo último que se haga.

```
while(true){
    int a = getchar();
    if( isdigit(a) ){
    puts("OK");
    break;
    }

    else
    printf("Error");
}
```